# Use NDSolve within loop

Tags: differential-equations

I want to find out the series of solution of thsol, th0 and b varying Fy from 0 to 10000. But I'm new to mathematica and do not know how to write a for loop with NDSolve. Here is my code:

```
EE = 114*10^9
h = 0.02
b = 0.1
LL = 1
Fy = 0
MM = 0
Fx = 0
II = h^3*b/12
thsol = NDSolve[{θ''[s]*EE*II == 
    Fx*Sin[θ[s]] - Fy*Cos[θ[s]], θ'[LL] == 
    MM/(EE*II), θ[0] == 0}, θ, {s, 0, LL}]
th0 = (Evaluate[θ[s] /. thsol]) /. s -> LL
b = NIntegrate[Sin[θ[s] /. thsol], {s, 0, LL}]
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use the `Table` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by [C.E.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/731/c-e), the simplest solution is to use a `Table` to wrap your code. (You need to add some `CompoundExpression`(`;`), of course. )

```
lst = Table[
    EE = 114*10^9;
    h = 0.02;
    b = 0.1;
    LL = 1;
    MM = 0;
    Fx = 0;
    II = h^3*b/12;
    thsol = 
     NDSolve[{θ''[s]*EE*II == 
        Fx*Sin[θ[s]] - Fy*Cos[θ[s]], θ'[LL] == 
        MM/(EE*II), θ[0] == 0}, θ, {s, 0, LL}];
    th0 = (Evaluate[θ[s] /. thsol]) /. s -> LL;
    b = NIntegrate[Sin[θ[s] /. thsol], {s, 0, LL}];
    {thsol, th0, b}, {Fy, 0, 10000, 100}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {8.664614, Null} *)
lst[[All, 3]] // Flatten // ListPlot
```

But it's not the most effective way. Using `ParametricNDSolveValue` and calculate the integration inside it will make the code much faster:

```
{EE = 114 10^9, h = 0.02, b = 0.1, LL = 1, MM = 0, Fx = 0, II = h^3 b/12};
thsolpara = 
  ParametricNDSolveValue[{θ''[s] EE II == 
     Fx Sin[θ@s] - Fy Cos[θ@s], θ'[LL] == 
     MM/(EE II), θ[0] == 0, intSin'[s] == Sin[θ@s], 
    intSin[0] == 0}, {θ, θ[LL], intSin[LL]}, {s, 0, LL}, Fy];

lst2 = thsolpara /@ Range[0, 10000, 100]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {3.102206, Null} *)
lst2[[All, 3]] // ListPlot
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you so much! They are exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @joy You can [click the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/) to accept my answer if you're satisfied with it :)

Comment: Sure, I just did it! It's my first time to post on stackexchange too, thanks for letting me know!